# How do I test an image alt value using capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, webrat, capybara

I'm trying to define a step to test the value of alt text of an image using Capybara and CSS selectors.

I wrote one for input values based on the readme examples:

```
Then /^I should see a value of "([^\"]*)" within the "([^\"]*)" input$/ do |input_value, input_id|
  element_value = locate("input##{input_id}").value
  element_value.should == input_value
end
```

But I can't figure this one out...something like:

```
Then /^I should see the alttext "([^\"]*)"$/ do | alt_text |
  element_value = locate("img[alt]").value
end
```

Anyone know how I can locate the alt text value?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Capybara uses xpath by default, so unless you changed that setting, that could be part of your problem. (You could use `locate(:css, "img[alt]")`).

I would write the tests using xpath to look something like this:

```
Then /^I should see the alt text "([^\"]*)"$/ do | alt_text |
    page.should have_xpath("//img[@alt=#{alt_text}]")
end

Then /^I should see a value of "([^\"])" within the "([^\"])" input$/ do |input_value, input_id|
    page.should have_xpath("//input[@id=#{input_id} and text()=#{input_value}]
end
```

Comment: Thanks Eliza - I did change the default setting as we mostly use the CSS selectors

Answer (score 11):

I believe the `value` method returns the value of input fields and cannot be used to test an attribute.

Something like this might work instead:

```
page.should have_css("img[alt=the_alt_text_you_are_expecting]")
```

Answer (score 6):

another variation on the theme:

```
Then /^I should see the image alt "([^"]*)"$/ do |alt_text|
  page.should have_css('img', :alt => alt_text)
end
```

Comment: Very simple, but this did not work for me. (RSpec 3.0 + Capybara 2.4)

Comment: This would return `invalid keys :alt` now. I am not sure if this ever worked?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the method you're using to find the image but this works for me:

```
expect(find_by_id("image-1")[:alt]).to have_content('tree')
```

Once you have the element the `[:"tag"]` will give you the value.

```
$thing = find_by_id("image-1")[:alt]
```

will set thing to the value if you have more complex tests.